# Conducted/Radiated emissions through 40-pin FFC cable

Tags: emc, cables, emissions, emc-filtering

I have a 40 pin FFC cable that looks like this between 2 PCB's:

[image]
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0151660427/3281308

[image]

The problem is I'm getting radiated emissions from mostly the cable.

[image]

I'm thinking that shorting - at minimum - the power rails on the cable (there are three) to ground would stop most of the high frequency emissions on the cable. The cable does have interleaved grounds every 4 conductors.

[image]

There are no comm lines operating above 50MHz
So I need to short out all frequencies above - say - 70MHz.

I am wondering if anyone has had a similar experience. What is a good way to short out the high frequency rails to ground? Would a simple 0.1uF cap work? Do I need low ESL caps?

More on the digital. There are 2 I2C lines 2 PWM lines, and I2S and UART and SPI bus, none operate more than 30MHz. All go to a processor that operates at 1GHz. I also don't see these frequencies with PCB1 detached and the cable hanging or any radiation in those frequencies when I look at PCB2.

Comment: How fast are the edges on the signals?  That is really the critical variable, not the frequency.

Comment: What else is connected to the PCBs? How are the power/ground lines connected at both ends? Why only every 4th?

Comment: There is an ethernet cable connected on one board. I don't have enough space to use a bigger cable.

Comment: Ground is interleaved every 4 conductor, so you have 3 signals between each ground line? If yes I bet it's your source of emission.

Comment: You could do an RC LP filter. Just adding a small resistor right at the output of whatever is pushing the signal on the board could already help. You should also check if the chip offers a soft mode for the GPIOs. The return path should be the top priority still.

Comment: Can you specify the peak frequencies?  I don't see the frequency scale of the display. There are at least two signals superimposed. My guess is, one of them is related to Ethernet square wave clock, and the other could be MDI. Is that 100Base-TX, and with MII or RMII? Care to provide the pinout on the connector?

Comment: @Justme In the image the starting frequency is 30MHz and ends at 1GHZ, every division is ~100MHz. The ethernet square wave clock does not run through the connector, but it could be bleeding from somewhere else. I also don't see these frequencies with PCB1 detached and the cable hanging  in the air.

Comment: @VoltageSpike Are those peaks perhaps at 343, 312, 281, 250, 218, 225, 200, 175, 125 MHz? I.e. multiples of 25 and 31.25 MHz? Also if comm lines run at max 50 MHz, you likely can't cut off at 70 MHz, as signals need to look like square waves, not sine waves, so you need maybe 250 MHz.

Comment: Are you sure is due to field-to-cable coupling ? If you wrap your FCC cable in aluminum foil, connected to GND on both sides, what do you see on the spectrum analyzer ?

Comment: Have you tried the venerable clamp on ferrite?

Comment: I'm assuming it's conducted because it only happens when the boards are connected.

Comment: Flat, unshielded ribbon cables are terrible from a radiated emissions point of view.  You've made the situation worse by having a ground/return every 4 pins.  This just increases the loop area of the signal & its return, which increases radiated emissions.

Comment: Fixes, I'm in the middle of EVT and precompliance

Comment: @Voltage Spike - Do you have an RE spec you're trying to meet, or is this just a "I'd like to see it better" desire?  If it's the former, how much more attenuation do you need?

Comment: @SteveSH The comment isn't clear, are you suggesting insufficient pins?

Comment: @Erik Friesen - My first comment, YES.  Number of pins (conductors, actually) for ground/return should be increased.   Idea is to minimized the loop area for the signal and it's return.

Comment: It would be nice to see the actual layout and signaling of the cable and both ends.  Ideally, any high speed stuff should use differential signaling on pairs. Then lower speed stuff should be edge filtered somehow.

Comment: Ended up making a custom 40 pin cable at pcbway with shielding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up making a 40 pin cable based off of the molex drawing at pcbway and it worked really well! It cut 5-10dB off each spike, so it was for sure the cable.

Also added 10 ohm resistors in series, have to wait to see if that worked as it's a cheaper option.

Comment: Glad that worked out for you.  FYI I had a similar situation except mine was one assembly - rigid PCB -> flex -> rigid PCB.  I put hatched ground layers on top & bottom of the flex in order to carry the shielding through the design.